# Phonegap Cordova 1.7.0 full exit app android

Tags: android, cordova, exit, kill

I use Cordova 1.7.0, though tried with 1.6.1 and invoked all methods of full exiting app I found on the internet. But my android app always remains running in background.
I use:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
          if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') === 'homePage') {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
            } else {
              window.history.back();
            }
        }, false);
```

Now, it exits fully on simulator, but never on the device. Is there a sure way to kill Phonegap app on exit in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK, 
    function() {   
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'page') { 
          blackberry.app.exit();
          return false;
        } 
        else { 
          history.back(); 
          return false;
        } 
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

From the Javadoc:

```
 // Enable app to keep running in background. (Boolean - default=true)
 super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", false);
```

Update: forgot to mention that you need to add this line in the main activity class, which extends DroidGap, like this:

```
public class RSSDemoActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", false);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```